# Having dynamic text with MSGID in DSPF

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I'm modifying an interactive program, having DSPF with an Output field:

```
MSGERR        80A  O 24  2MSGID(&§MSGID FILE_MSG)
```

I pass an ID into MSGID and it's work perfectly.

Now I have a message like this:

```
VALUE CAN BE: &1, &2, &3
```

and I need to replace &1, &2, &3 with a TEXT.

Is it possible using the current method? 
Because I can't operate directly on MSGERR on RPGLE, because it isn't visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. Instead of using MSGID, ERRMSGID, etc. I prefer a message subfile. It looks like this:

```
 A* ========================================================================
 A* Message Subfile
 A* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A          R MSGSFL                    SFL
 A                                      SFLMSGRCD(24)
 A            MSGKEY                    SFLMSGKEY
 A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ
 A* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A* Message Subfile - Control forrmat
 A* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A          R MSGCTL                    SFLCTL(MSGSFL)
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A                                      SFLINZ
 A                                      SFLPAG(1)
 A                                      SFLSIZ(2)
 A                                      SFLDSP SFLDSPCTL
 A  52
 AON52                                  SFLEND(*PLUS)
 A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ
```

To use it you send messages to a program message queue, and then write MSGCTL as part of you screen transaction. So if you normally have a single record format on you screen named RECORD, you would do this:

```
pgmq = <Program Name>;
write msgctl;
exfmt record;
```

Any messages that are in the program message queue will be displayed in a one line subfile at line 24 on your display. This subfile is scrollable.

You will need two sub-procedures to make this work easily, one to write the message, and another to clear the message queue. I name mine `ClearDspfMsg(pgmq)` and `SendDspfMsg(pgmq: msgid: msgdata)`.

Here are the procedures:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Clear Display File Messages
// Clears the messages in the display file message subfile
//
// Parameters:
//  pgmq        - Program message queue. This must be the same as the pgmq
//                specified in the display file.
// ------------------------------------
dcl-proc ClearDspfMsg Export;
  dcl-pi *n;
    pgmq           Char(10) const;
  end-pi;

  dcl-ds ec            LikeDs(errCode_t) Inz(*LikeDs);

  qmhrmvpm(pgmq: 0: '': '*ALL': ec);
  // TODO Provide error checking here
end-proc;

// ------------------------------------
// Send Message to Display File (MSGID)
// Sends a message to the display file message subfile
//
// Parameters:
//  pgmq        - Program message queue. This must be the same as the pgmq
//                specified in the display file.
//  messageId   - The message id of the message to be sent
//  messageData - Message data for replacement values in the message. Format
//                of the message data is defined by the message. This is
//                optional, if missing, blanks are used.
//  messageFile - The qualified name of the message file containing the
//                message. The first 10 characters is the messafe file name,
//                the second 10 characters is the library. This is optional,
//                if blank, CNVMSG in *LIBL is used.
// ------------------------------------
dcl-proc SendDspfMsg Export;
  dcl-pi *n;
    pgmq           Char(10) const;
    messageId      Char(7) const;
    messageData    Varchar(256) const options(*varsize: *nopass);
    messageFile    LikeDs(qualName_t) const options(*nopass);
  end-pi;

  dcl-ds msgf      LikeDs(qualName_t) Inz(*likeds);
  dcl-ds ec        LikeDs(errCode_t) Inz(*likeds);

  dcl-s msgData    Char(256) Inz('');

  if %parms() >= %parmnum(messageData);
    msgData = messageData;
  endif;
  if %parms() >= %parmnum(messageFile);
    msgf = messageFile;
  else;
    msgf.name = 'MSGF';  // This is your default message file
  endif;

  qmhsndpm(messageId: msgf: msgData: %size(msgData): '*INFO': pgmq: 0: '': ec);
  // TODO Provide error checking here
end-proc;
```

I have prototypes for `qmhsndpm` and `qmhrmvpm`, but you can look up those and the format of the error code parameter in the documentation easily enough.

Call `SendDspfgMsg()` to send a message, and `ClearDspfMsg()` to clear the message queue at the beginning of your transaction. PGMQ should have the same value for all of these parts, and it will just work.

**NOTE:** This will not work for RPG since you don't have access to sub-procedures. If necessary, convert your program to RPGLE, and it will work fine. Or use subroutines rather than sub-procedures in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can't modify this DSPF. I have solved calling a Pgm with Window showing the message.